# How to use aar files in android project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, aar

I have spent a lot of hours in this. I have created two library projects lets say A and B. **Project B has dependency over A**, so I used A as aar in library project B.

Now I have created an android application which has dependency over library project B. I have added aar file for project B in my application. So far I am able to access files created in B project from my android application but I am **unable to access files of A project**.

I guess B comprises of files defined by itself and A project( let me know if I am wrong). Now I have to use A and B project's aar in my application which I don't think is good because B is already using A. Can anybody suggest how to build a library project which depends on other project's aar file so as to access files from both the projects?

I am sorry If I am unable to explain what it is?

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps Very easy to add `arr` file in `android studio.`

**Step A:**

[image]

**Step B:**

[image]

**Step C:**

[image]

**Step D:**

[image]

**Step E:**

[image]

**Step F:**

[image]

**Step G:**

[image]

You are Done.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps:

- Extract the aar
- In the extracted folder you have `classes.jar`
- Place the jar file in the libs folder of your Project B & add to build path
- Mark your Project B as library (in the properties -> Android scroll to     bottom and check the checkbox)
- Add your Project B as library to main project

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to do this in android studio, I am able to import aar files and reference it.

Comment: I tried it in eclipse long ago to implement cardview as only aar was available at that time but haven't implemented in android studio